# OmniAuth + Devise + Rails 3 fails in production with Error::EACCES

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

On my local machine Google auth is working fine but when I release to my production server on Dreamhost I get the following error when I click on the Google auth button on my login page.

```
Started GET "/auth/google?openid_url=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" for [REMOVED IP] at Wed May 25 08:47:01 -0700 2011

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /tmp/associations/https-www.google.com-apdYYPrtQGUIj7Vp7jMTz.Kn74A-ZmpumY7Issy.P1r4_X0d6_oGqkI):
```

I temporarily chmod'd the tmp folder to 777 but I still get the permission denied error. What else can I try?

TIA

Comment: Did you chmod the associations directory to 777 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get it to work with the filesystem, a lot of people have used a database or memcached store.

See the documentation:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/OpenID-and-Google-Apps

This example app was written for Heroku, but the problem is the same (couldn't configure write access properly):
https://github.com/madhums/omniauth-on-heroku/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look into storing in the database

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your OpenID filestore is setup correctly, ie..

`OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp')`

(Notice the . in front of the /tmp)